# PHP/MySQL store sum in separate table or compute everytime

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I need to store points for users. Each point is to be stored in a separate row with a date. Now, when a user opens his page, it will display the total points for him.

Now to calculate the total points, I can think of the following options:

1. Every time the user opens his page, calculate the sum of all his points in that ONE mysql table and display it to him
2. Create another table for the total points, and whenever a point is added, calculate the sum, and replace the previous sum value with the new one. When user opens his page, it only accesses that ONE row in that total sum table and displays the value to him
3. Create a CRON job to run everynight to calculate the user's total point and store it in the separate table created in (2)

To me, option no 2 looks efficient, but just want to know how something like that is normally done?

Comment: How many users will you have, and how often will the point values change?  Will you be storing an audit trail so that you can re-compute point values if they become corrupted?

Comment: For Option 2, instead of recalculating the sum you can just += the points field.

Comment: For an efficiency question we are going to need some more information about how often things are going to occur. Something like this can be done many different ways, it really depends on the amount of volume you are talking about

Comment: Lets say I have around 3000 users to start with and around 500 users' points being changed daily, and yes, I need each point addition in each row for audit purpose, as these are not just points, but have a lot more meaning.

Comment: I would probably go with choice #1 but cache the result so you don't have to recalculate every time he reloads the page. It's probably not difficult to switch between any of these methods so your best bet is probably to implement whichever is simplest now (probably 1) and change it later only if you find that it is slowing your app down in real-world usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the proper permissions you can create a trigger on the points table.

```
delimiter | 
create trigger update_point_total 
    after insert on points for each row 
    begin
    update point_totals set total=total+NEW.points
    where userid=NEW.userid;
    end
|
delimiter;
```

This will cause the total points column to update each time a row is inserted into your points table.

Comment: Thanks. Haven't thought about triggers. It looks like a simple thing to do, at the same time removing part of the functions from my PHP code.